# Optimization problem for a Gaussian Process

Tags: optimization, gaussian-process

I have to find the best values of 3 sigmas, to put them into the Kernel of a Gaussian Process (which I have already implemented). In order to find them, I implement an optimization problem of this kind:

```
def NegLogLikelihood(theta,X,y ):

KernelConst = MyKernel(sigma_l,sigma_f,sigma)
H=KernelConst.__call__(X)
n = X.shape[0]
#y = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean=np.zeros(n), cov=H)
inv_H = np.linalg.inv(H)
DetH = np.linalg.det(H)
print(DetH)
LnLike = -0.5 * y.T @ inv_H @ y - 0.5 * np.log(DetH) - 0.5 * n * np.log(2*np.pi)
print(LnLike)
return -LnLike

def sed(Xtrain):

distance = np.zeros((Xtrain.shape\[0\], Xtrain.shape\[0\]))
for i in range(Xtrain.shape\[0\]):
      distance\[i, :\]=-np.sqrt(np.sum((Xtrain\[i, :\] - Xtrain) \*\* 2, axis=1))
return distance

def cons(theta):
sigma_l, sigma_f, sigma = theta
H = sigma_f \*\* 2 \* np.exp(-sed(Xtrain)/ sigma_l) + sigma \*\* 2 \* np.eye(len(Xtrain))
return np.linalg.matrix_rank(H)-Xtrain.shape\[0\]

initial_guess=\[0.20, 1.02, 0.3\]
bnds=\[(1, None), (0, None), (1, None)\]
OurConstraint=({'type': 'eq', 'fun': cons})
Xtrain=df_regressors_train.to_numpy()
y=resGPXTrain.to_numpy()
res = minimize(NegLogLikelihood, initial_guess, args=(Xtrain,y, ),bounds=bnds,constraints=OurConstraint, method='SLSQP')
```

`

With this specific code, the optimal sigmas returned from the minimize in scipy seems not to change from the initial guess. Any clue? Thank you for the attention

Comment: Your Python is invalid: you have to revisit the indentation